# Create and Write files in windows 8.1 store apps by JavaScript and WinJS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, winjs, windows-8.1

I am building a app for win 8.1 store and i need to create some files during app execution. how this is possible only by js or WinJS. i found command for writing and reading but not for creating.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.createfileasync

Comment: Also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464978.aspx

Take a look at the first couple of steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
  folder.createFileAsync(
           fileName, 
           Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting, 
           Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.utf8
  );
```

the folder object can be a [StorageFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.aspx) object, like for example:

```
 Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

The http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.createfileasync link should do it for you. The creation of files is pretty much implicit to the write.